# How do you configure UDPInput to work with heka-flood udp test

Tags: udp, config, hekad

I am trying to test sending data to heka's UDPInput with no success. I decided to try to use the heka-flood tool to mimic UPD traffic also with no success. I am using 0.10 version of heka. My heka.toml :

```
[UdpInput]
address = "127.0.0.1:4880"
net = "udp"
splitter = "udp_splitter"
decoder = "ProtobufDecoder"
set_hostname = true
# I have also tried not setting this as well

[udp_splitter]
type = "HekaFramingSplitter"

[ProtobufDecoder]

[LogOutput]
type = "LogOutput"
message_matcher = "Logger == 'UdpInput'"
encoder = "PayloadEncoder"
```

and my flood.toml:

```
[udp_proto]
ip_address          = "127.0.0.1:4880"
sender              = "udp"  
pprof_file          = ""
encoder             = "protobuf"
num_messages        = 1000
corrupt_percentage  = 0.0001
signed_percentage   = 0.00011
variable_size_messages = false
ascii_only          = true
max_message_size    = 32000
```

If I add another input, like say a log tailer and add it to the message matcher for the LogOutput, those messages end up being logged out. I never see anything from the UpdInput. What am I doing wrong?